# Add multiple rows with relation many-to-many

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, many-to-many, laravel-5.4

I'm trying to save a multiple database records with image name and thumb(for now only text inputs). Every image has also a category/categories (made by multiselect and pivot table between image and categories with many to many relation). The question is: how to sync/attach those categories? I do not want to use foreach ::create, because it will generate unnecessary database requests. For now I have something like this:

my blade file (part in form)

```
<form action="/panel/images" method="POST">
{{ csrf_field() }}

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="row[1][title]">Image title</label>
        <input type="text" name="row[1][title]" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="row[1][thumb]">Thumb</label>
        <input type="text" name="row[1][thumb]" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <!-- date because insert methode don't create timestamps autimatically-->
    <input type="hidden" name="row[1][created_at]" value="{{ $date }}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="row[1][updated_at]" value="{{ $date }}" />

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="multi[0][]">Categories</label>
        <select name="multi[0][]" multiple>
            @include('layouts.images_categories_select')
        </select>
    </div>



    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="row[2][title]">Image title</label>
        <input type="text" name="row[2][title]" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="row[2][thumb]">Thumb</label>
        <input type="text" name="row[2][thumb]" class="form-control" />
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="multi[1][]">Categories</label>
        <select name="multi[1][]" multiple>
            @include('layouts.images_categories_select')
        </select>
    </div>

    <input type="text" name="row[2][created_at]" value="{{ $date }}" />
    <input type="text" name="row[2][updated_at]" value="{{ $date }}" />


    <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>      

 </form>
```

And the controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{                
    $image = new Image;    
    $inputs = Input::get('row');
    $multiSelect = Input::get('multi');

    $image::insert($inputs);        

    $image->images_catetories()->sync($multiSelect);
    return redirect()->route('newImage')->with('status', 'images added');

}
```

EDIT:
Right now it throws an error "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `image_images_category` (`0`, `image_id`, `images_category_id`, `1`) values (18, , 1, 19))"

where "image_images_category" is my pivot table and values 18, 1, 19 are from multiselect.

Comment: What happens when you run existing code? What's wrong with the existing code? What's the actual problem? You say that you don't want to run foreach yet you don't run foreach anywhere.

Comment: I have edited my question (you can see result error). About foreach: there are some solutions with foreach and save single row in every step like here [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/how-to-insert-multiple-rows-with-multiple-fields), but it creates many db requests.